# How do I convert this query into one using joins/unions in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

My join and union skills are rudimentary at best. Could some body help me change the below query into something more efficient?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Doc2ChaptAssignment]
(
    [DocID_FK] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [mChapterID_FK] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chapters]
(
    [mChapterID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Chapter Name] [varchar](128) NOT NULL
)
```

and here is the query

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm varchar(128) = 'Chapter One'

SELECT
    [mChapterID], [ChapterName]
FROM 
    [dbo].[ModuleChapters]
WHERE 
    [mChapterID] NOT IN (SELECT [mChapterID_FK]
                         FROM [dbo].[Doc2ChaptAssignment]
                         WHERE [DocID_FK] = @SearchTerm)
    AND [ChapterName] LIKE '%'+@1+'%'
ORDER BY 
    [ChapterName]
```

Answer (score 4):

They way you have it written is one way. It's often seen using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
   [mChapterID]
  ,[ChapterName]
FROM [dbo].[ModuleChapters]
WHERE [mChapterID] NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM [dbo].[Doc2ChaptAssignment]
                           WHERE [DocID_FK] = @SearchTerm
                           AND [mChapterID_FK] = [mChapterID])
AND [ChapterName] LIKE '%'+@1+'%'
ORDER BY [ChapterName]
```

Less commonly, it's seen as a `JOIN`

```
SELECT
   [mChapterID]
  ,[ChapterName]
FROM [dbo].[ModuleChapters]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Doc2ChaptAssignment] on [mChapterID_FK] = [mChapterID]
WHERE [ChapterName] LIKE '%'+@1+'%' 
AND [mChapterID_FK] IS NULL
ORDER BY [ChapterName]
```

You probably won't see a performance increase right away, because none of your columns are NULLable. However, if that ever changes, `NOT IN` will have to do more *work* to get the same results, and thus `NOT EXISTS` would be faster. As it stands, we would need to see the execution plan and your DDL statements for any indexes. Check this blog about [getting help with a slow query.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/).

Of note, you have a [non-SARGable predicate](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/) which means an index seek can't  be used for this part `[ChapterName] LIKE '%'+@1+'%'`. [Brent Ozar explains why this is slow,](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/) but the short of it is if you *can* drop that leading % then you *could* see a performance increase. Or, even better, if you can use the `=` operand (you aren't searching for Chapters "like" the term), and you have a covering index, it could be a lot faster.

Comment: And maybe drop the `ORDER BY` if you don't need it! (*Also not guaranteed to increase performance depending on the indexing)